# Selenium Webdriver: stale element reference

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Am getting the below error:

stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.
When I select a country from the country dropdown the page gets refreshed since we have used 'onchange' attribute, so when i try to locate rest of the fields in the form its throwing me the stated exception.

Note: I have cross verified the locators before and after the page gets loaded,
there is no change in it as most of the locators used are id's.

Here is my HTML,

```
<form method="post" action="/eClaims/app" name="mainForm" id="mainForm"
    accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="formids"
            value="ifErrors,hasErrors,If,If_0,statusDate1,If_1,If_3,If_5,If_7,If_2,callDate,If_8,If_4,countryList,If_9,If_6,languageList,If_10,If_11,If_12,customerEmail,If_13,If_14,customerTitle,If_15,customerFirstName,If_16,If_17,customerLastName,If_18,customerCompany,If_19,If_20,If_21,customerFaxPhoneCode,customerFaxNumber,If_22,If_23,customerPhoneCode,customerPhoneNumber,If_24,If_25,qualificationSystem,If_26,If_27,caseId,If_28,If_29,productNumber,If_30,If_31,serialNumber,If_32,If_33,If_34,purchaseDate,If_35,If_36,problemDescription,If_37,qualificationAgent,If_38,If_39,If_40,cancelDoaAuth,If_41,Submit_0,If_42,Submit_1,If_43,Submit_2,If_44,If_45,If_46,If_47,Submit_6,Submit_7,Submit_8">
        <input type="hidden" name="component" value="mainForm"> <input
            type="hidden" name="page" value="DoaAuthorisationForm">
    </div>
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="theme">
                <th width="100%" colspan="3">
                    <h2 class="themeheader">Authorisation to return DOA product</h2>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="10"><font color="red">please obtain a valid
                        proof of purchase from the customer before proceeding with this
                        form.&nbsp;</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><hr width="100%"></td>
            </tr>

            <!-- <tr style="visibility: hidden;">
                        <td>
                            <span key="label.status" ></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inputFormCell">
                            <span jwcid="statusList" ></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr> -->
            <tr style="visibility: hidden;">
                <td>Status Date</td>
                <td class="inputFormCell"><input type="text" name="statusDate1"
                    value="" title="dd MMM yyyy" id="statusDate1">&nbsp;<a
                    href="javascript:calendar_statusDate1.toggle(document.mainForm.statusDate1);"><img
                        src="/eClaims/app?digest=d1154f8b7bf653ba6128f8cb1f5c8e95&amp;path=%2Forg%2Fapache%2Ftapestry%2Fform%2FDatePickerIcon.png&amp;service=asset"
                        border="0"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Call Date<font color="red"> *</font>
                </td>
                <td class="inputFormCell"><input type="text" name="callDate"
                    value="" title="dd MMM yyyy" id="callDate">&nbsp;<a
                    href="javascript:calendar_callDate.toggle(document.mainForm.callDate);"><img
                        src="/eClaims/app?digest=d1154f8b7bf653ba6128f8cb1f5c8e95&amp;path=%2Forg%2Fapache%2Ftapestry%2Fform%2FDatePickerIcon.png&amp;service=asset"
                        border="0"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Country<font color="red"> *</font>
                </td>
                <td class="inputFormCell"><select name="countryList"
                    id="countryList" style="width: 180px;"
                    onchange="javascript:onChangeCountry(this);">
                        <option value="">--please select--</option>
                        <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                        <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
                        <option value="AU" selected="selected">Australia</option>
                        <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
                        <option value="WF">Wallis And Futuna</option>
                        <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td>Language<font color="red"> *</font>
                </td>
                <td class="inputFormCell"><select name="languageList"
                    id="languageList" style="width: 180px;">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--please select--</option>
                        <option value="EN">English</option>
                </select></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Customer Email<font color="red"> *</font><font color="red">
                        *</font>
                </td>
                <td class="inputFormCell"><input type="text"
                    name="customerEmail" value="" id="customerEmail"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">**Fax Number mandatory for 'Save &amp; Fax',
                    e-Mail mandatory for 'Save &amp; Mail'</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="section_content"><input type="submit"
                    name="Submit_6" value="[BUTTON.SUBMIT1]" id="submitDummy"
                    class="primButton" style="visibility: hidden;"></td>
                <td class="section_content"><input type="submit"
                    name="Submit_7" value="[BUTTON.SUBMIT2]" id="submitAuth"
                    class="primButton" style="visibility: hidden;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="section_content"><input type="submit"
                    name="Submit_8" value="[BUTTON.SUBMIT2]" id="submitMailAuth"
                    class="primButton" style="visibility: hidden;"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

I have tried the following solutions,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 500)
        .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
        .until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
            public boolean apply(@Nullable WebDriver driver) {
                Select selectLanguage;
                try {
                    selectLanguage = new Select(getWebElement("apj.newdoa.language"));
                    selectLanguage.selectByValue("EN");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

2nd Solution,

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout( 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
                .pollingEvery( 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
                .ignoring( NoSuchElementException.class, StaleElementReferenceException.class );
        // using a customized expected condition
        Select foo1 = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Select>() {
            Select selectLanguage;
            public Select apply(WebDriver driver) {
                try {
                    selectLanguage = new Select(getWebElement("apj.newdoa.language"));
                    logger.info("Value of Option:\t" +selectLanguage.toString());
                    return selectLanguage = new Select(getWebElement("apj.newdoa.language"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return selectLanguage;
            }
        });

        foo1.selectByValue("EN");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: After the page si reloaded all your current objects are lost, you need to recreate/find them each time the mage changes.

Comment: But am still able to locate the element with same id or xpath

Comment: Yes you are, but what happens, you find the element (an object is created that you can use to call methods on it) then if the page is reloaded, the object is lost and not attached to the page (the object of the page) and results in stale element.